# Restart Internet Explorer midway during Excel VBA execution

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a HTML scraping excel tool to visit a website and search for a code that I put in Column A (upto 300) and pull all relevant information into the adjacent columns. The problem is that a process called iexplore*32.exe starts and keeps hogging memory and it takes up 1.2GB of RAM until VBA crashes.

```
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
         .Visible = False
          For j = 2 To i  

         .navigate "https://google.com/dp/" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1)

         "My code"
         Next j

    End With

    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing
```

The ie.quit doesnt seem to be working as I see that the process is not being killed. Is there a way where I can kill the process at a certain interval say j=50. Can I can restart the IE process so that the program doesn't crash?

Comment: You could add an if condition where every time `j Mod 50 = 0`, you set a new instance of IE. I haven't tested it though, just giving you a possibility... Alternatively you can Set IE every time at the start of the loop and set it back to nothing at the end of the loop, but that's going to be slooooow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make it visible so you know if it's closing out or not?

Instead of defining ie as an object, you can do it as "Dim ie as InternetExplorer" then use "Set ie = new InternetExplorer".

Are you setting ie to equal Nothing during "My code"? Also, it doesn't show where you end the with statement, but "Quit ie" and "Set ie = Nohting" should be after the end with.

```
dim ie as InternetExplorer

Set ie = new InternetExplorer
With ie
.Visible = False

For j = 2 To i  

.navigate "https://google.com/dp/" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(j, 1)

 "My code"

 End with

 ie.Quit
 Set ie = Nothing
```

EDIT

This may be a little extreme, but you can set up a Sub that will just kill all IE processes if one of them is using memory beyond an established ceiling like this. The problem with this solution is that it will terminate ALL IE processes that are running. In this example it's using 20MB as the ceiling, you may want to raise it to 250MB or higher.

```
Sub KillHighestMemIEProcess()

Dim oServ As Object
Dim cProc As Variant
Dim oProc As Object

Set oServ = GetObject("winmgmts:")
Set cProc = oServ.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process")

For Each oProc In cProc

If oProc.Name = "iexplore.exe" And oProc.WorkingSetSize / 2400000 > 20 Then 'greater than the MB ceiling
    Shell ("taskkill /F /IM iexplore.exe /T")
    Exit Sub
End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I think his issue is that while it navigates (inside the loop), it starts using more and more memory.

Comment: Yes it keeps adding up... starts at 50MB and by the time I'm through with 50 rows, I'll be staring at 1 GB and crashes after reaching 1.3GB.

Comment: @Alex - I tried .Visible=True. Although the window gets closed I can still see it in the task manager iexplore.exe *32. I'm using the "End With" after it loops through all the items that I put in column A

Comment: Hey, check out the edit on my initial post. I may have found a dirty solution for your problem.

Comment: Hi Alex. Where exactly do I put in my code? I'm new to VBA

Comment: Copy the code into a module, then you can put "KillHighestMemIEProcess" in any line where you want it to execute, you could put it between the end with and ie.quit.

Comment: Awesome! No problem.

Comment: It goes up to 1.5GB and just crashes